# resolving clean urls from single php file using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK, so what I want to do is request urls on my site as follows:

http://example.com/login, http://example.com/register, etc. (also resolving trailing slashes)

with an index.php file in the root with a get parameter as follows{

http://example.com/?v=login, http://example.com/?v=register, etc.

I found the following while searching:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

So I figured if I just adjust it slightly I can make it work, so I changed it to:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /?v=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

This doesn't seem to work at all.. can anyone please tell me the error of my ways?

Answer (score 1):

`[0-9]` is template for digits. use dot (.) to select any symbol

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?v=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to just forward me to the /?v=login url when i hit /login

Comment: @thatgerhard Try to remove slash

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: I want the end product to be 'http://example.com/login' and the way that would work is 'http://example.com/?v=login'

Comment: *forward me to the /?v=login url when i hit /login* - It's not what you ask?